# How to omit "index" entry from an autogenerated Docusaurus V2 sidebar

Tags: sidebar, docusaurus

At work we have a basic Docusaurus v2 page for user documentation, and I can't share it for privacy reasons. Suffice it to say it has a sidebar which is autogenerated, where the top level contains a number of folders as categories and each category only contains `.md` files.

At the top level (the level of the categories) there is an empty `index.md` file that only exists so that the page will load. The autogenerated sidebar includes an `index` entry that points to a blank page. I would like to hide/get rid of this entry.

I have looked at [this github discussion](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/6127) on something similar, but I haven't been able to make the solutions work. The `sidebar.js` file has the following simple contents:

```
module.exports = {
  docs: [
    {
      type: 'autogenerated',
      dirName: '.'
    },
  ],
};
```

I have tried adding an `exclude: ['path\to\index\file']` line, but this results in the error `"exclude" is not allowed`.

What is the proper way of hiding this index entry from the sidebar? Alternatively, is there a way to set up the site so that the `index.md` file is not needed at all?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution for this? I am facing the same and it kinda drives me nuts :)

Comment: @Ovi I'm not sure if it's a "solution" as it doesn't accomplish what I intended, but we ended up just giving the file the title "Introduction" and adding an introductory blurb to it, so that now at least it seems less out-of-place.

Comment: hahaha, thank you! I did the same thing as well :)
it's a hack but I could not find a better solution

Comment: From what I can see it looks like this is a planned feature - https://docusaurus.canny.io/feature-requests/p/hiding-parts-of-docs-in-autogenerated-sidebar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same setup:

```
/folder1
  /file
/folder2
  /file
index
```

And I wand to autogenerate the sidebar with two categories only:

- folder1
- folder2

Moreover, I wanted to click on the navbar and see `index`.

I was able to do so by:

#### Create a custom sidebar

```js
function skipIndex(items) {
  return items.filter(({ type, id }) => {
    return type !== 'doc' || id !== 'index';
  });
}

module.exports = async function sidebarItemsGenerator({ defaultSidebarItemsGenerator, ...args }) {
  const sidebarItems = await defaultSidebarItemsGenerator(args);
  return skipIndex(sidebarItems);
}
```

Then in the `docusaurus.config.js`

```js
  presets: [
    [
      'classic',
      ({
        // https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/plugins/@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs#configuration
        docs: {
          sidebarItemsGenerator: require('./sidebar.js'),
        },
```

And finally in the `index.md` file I must add this metadata, otherwise when I reach the `index` page, the sidebar disappears because the page is not included:

```
---
displayed_sidebar: docsSidebar
---
```